# How do I successfully install OpenPYXL on Mac?

Tags: python

I want to install openpyxl on my Mac for a survey project that I am doing, however I ran into some issues in the process.

I typed `pip install openpyxl` in the terminal and I received an error message saying this:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jdcal.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I am quite unfamiliar with how consoles work, can someone please help me?
Currently running Python 3.

Comment: The error message you put in says Python 2.7, but you say that you are running Python 3. Are you sure you are installing the correct version or could you elaborate more on it.

Comment: I think python 2.7 is the preinstalled version on my Mac but I installed python 3 by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sudo` in front of the command to get temporary root permission
Eg: `sudo pip install openpyxl`

**OR**

you can use `pip install --user openpyxl`